# Testing .NET Web API from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have a Visual Studio solution with two projects in it.

First project is a console application written in F#. The console application is actually a simple server with web API implementation.

Second project is a web application written in JavaScript. This project contains corresponding implementation of API, which allows users to make API requests to the server.

I need to test this client-side implementation of API to be sure that it passes the right data to the server and receives the right data back. **What is the best practice to achieve this?**

The problem is that I need to build and run the first project before I can run tests in a second project. What is also would be good is to make these tests running on Continuous Integration. If it is matter, I use visualstudio.com for CI.

**Is this possible at all without manual start of first project and then running tests?**

Note that on each test run it is important to restart console application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. I would recommend you to have a look at [RAML](http://raml.org/) which is a way of

- Documenting your API
- Using the documentation to generate a client and use it for automation tests
- Using [Anypoint](https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/) you can expose your documentation and get your stakeholders to easily test it as well.

Please have a look at [Design, test and document RESTful APIs using RAML in .NET](http://dusted.codes/design-test-and-document-restful-apis-using-raml-in-dotnet) for a full run through and explanation. In this blog post I used .NET at my language of choice, but the same principle applies to other languages.

With this you can test your API before you write the client. The Anypoint platform also allows you to mock the webservice and you can use the mock for testing you client later on.

This way you can test both applications in isolation and in a programmatic/automated manner (which you can execute from your CI). RAML has also a library for generating a JavaScript client from a RAML file: https://github.com/mulesoft/raml-client-generator